# Trying to split my GWT project into multiple modules - "did you forget to inherit a required module?"

Tags: java, maven, gwt

This is the first time I've attempted to split a GWT project into multiple modules, and I'm running into difficulties. My first project contains some common model & ui code; its module XML is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module rename-to="parentmodule">

<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>                     <!-- core -->
<inherits name='com.google.common.base.Base'/>                  <!-- Preconditions -->
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.inject.Inject'/>                 <!-- GIN -->
<inherits name='com.ekuefler.supereventbus.SuperEventBus'/>     <!-- event binding -->
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.logging.Logging"/>               <!-- console logging -->

<source path='client'/>
<source path='shared'/>
</module>
```

This is packaged by Maven as a JAR (parentmodule.jar).

I want to depend on this module from several child modules. So, for example, I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module rename-to="childmodule">

<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
<inherits name='com.foo.parentmodule'/>                             <!-- core -->

<source path='client'/>
<source path='shared'/>

<entry-point class='com.foo.Index'/>

</module>
```

My problem is that when the GWT compiler runs, it's unable to resolve common model classes; for example:

```
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 27: No source code is available for type com.foo.shared.model.User; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

Just to be clear, com.foo.shared.model.User is in parentmodule.jar. The maven dependency is set up correctly; the Java compiler (and my IDE) see nothing wrong with it. So what am I missing from this module setup?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to directly depend on `User`; the GWT dependencies are transient. The problem appears to be that you aren't including your source code in the `parentmodule` jar, and GWT needs source for all modules depended on.

There are a few ways to handle this; my preferred method is to determine which Maven artifacts need to be visible to GWT and then to add the necessary source files as Maven resources:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.java</include>
                <include>**/*.gwt.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Comment: Thank you. I had tried making a source jar, but it didn't occur to me to include source directly in my module jar.

Comment: @user717847 I think you could also include the source jar as a specific Maven dependency, but since GWT modules always need the source, I just package it in